# Image field causes #access to reset to default

Tags: 7, hooks

I am using ajax to show/hide a field based on a date field. I set the default access to TRUE. If the user selects a date of birth over 18 years old, `$is_younger` and consequently the access switch to FALSE.

```
function mrpeanut_form_record_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // some other stuff here
    $is_younger = TRUE;
    $values = !empty($form_state['values']) ? $form_state['values'] : array();
    $dob_date_combo_element = &$form['field_dob']['und'][0];
    $dob_date_combo_element['#ajax'] = [
      'callback' => 'mrpeanut_form_record_node_form_minor_agreement_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'minor-ajax',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ];

    if (!empty($values['field_dob']['und'][0]['value'])) {
      $dob = new DateTime($values['field_dob']['und'][0]['value']);
      $now = new DateTime();
      $age = $now->diff($dob)->y;
      $is_younger = $age < 18;
    }

    $form['field_minor_agreement']['und']['#access'] = $is_younger;
```

This is working great until the user selects and uploads an image on a separate image field. Then, `$is_younger` switches back to TRUE, regardless of whether they are over 18 or not. I can't seem to figure out why.

I think the error is happening on this line:

```
if (!empty($values['field_dob']['und'][0]['value']))
```

After I upload an image, I get this error if I try to watchdog the value.

> *Notice*: Undefined index: field_dob in
>   *mrpeanut_form_record_node_form_alter()*

I think `$values` is getting overwritten after the image is uploaded and therefore date of birth can't be calculated again and it reverts back to `$is_younger = TRUE`.

Here's my callback:

```
function mrpeanut_form_record_node_form_minor_agreement_callback($form, $form_state) {
  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#edit-field-minor-agreement-wrapper', drupal_render($form['field_minor_agreement']));
  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

Comment: is that drupal 7 or 8 , is that simple of code from form build function or callback function ?

Comment: Drupal 7 and sorry, that's from `hook_form_alter`. I'll update.

Comment: Could you post the code from `mrpeanut_form_record_node_form_minor_agreement_callback`? It might not be relevant but useful to rule it out nonetheless

Comment: Okay, added the callback.

Comment: Would I be better off storing `$is_younger` in a session variable like so -- `$_SESSION['is-younger'] = $is_younger` -- so that when `$values` gets overwritten, the variable is still there?

Comment: Interesting case @MrPeanut ; I haven't experienced this situation so far, but I can reproduce the problem locally. It surprises me that it hasn't been reported much (after some searching on the web). It does seem to be a side-effect from the core File's ajax logic. Below is a possible way to tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

I would try refactoring your code, so that the part that produces the value of `$is_younger` first checks whether the triggering element is the `field_dob` field.

As an example:

```
// some other stuff here
$dob_date_combo_element = &$form['field_dob']['und'][0];
$dob_date_combo_element['#ajax'] = [
  'callback' => 'mrpeanut_form_record_node_form_minor_agreement_callback',
  'wrapper' => 'minor-ajax',
  'effect' => 'fade',
];

// Were we called by the #ajax-ified element?
if (isset($form_state['triggering_element']) && 
  $form_state['triggering_element']['#name'] === 'field_dob[und][0][value]') {
  $values = !empty($form_state['values']) ? $form_state['values'] : array();
  $is_younger = TRUE;

  if (!empty($values['field_dob']['und'][0]['value'])) {
      $dob = new DateTime($values['field_dob']['und'][0]['value']);
      $now = new DateTime();
      $age = $now->diff($dob)->y;
      $is_younger = $age < 18;
  }
  $form['field_minor_agreement']['und']['#access'] = $is_younger;
}
// Initial form loading.
else if (empty($form_state['input']) {
  // Place initial loading logic here for field_minor_agreement.
}
```